# How to prove the combinatorial identity $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k (n-2k)^i=0$

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

This question arise from an analysis problem:

> If $f^{(n)}(0)$ exists, show that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{\binom{n}{k} (-1)^k f[(n-2k)h]}{(2h)^n}=f^{(n)}(0)$

I want to use Cauchy mean value theorem on $G(h)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k f[(n-2k)h]$ and $M(h)=(2h)^n$. I guess $G^{(i)}(0)=0$ i.e. $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k (n-2k)^i=0$, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality you suggest is valid only if either $i<n$ or $i,n$ are of different parity. In the following sketch of the proof I replaced $i$ with $m$ for convenience.

Consider the function:
$$
\sin^n x=\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^n=\frac1{(2i)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k
\binom nk e^{i(n-2k)x}$$

and differentiate it $m$ times:
$$
\frac{d^m\sin^nx}{d x^m}=\frac{i^m}{(2i)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k
\binom nk (n-2k)^m e^{i(n-2k)x}.
$$

Evaluating the equality for $x=0$ you will obtain the equation you need for $m<n$ or $m\ne n\pmod 2$.

Comment: Generally his equality is False, since you can check from n=2 . (Result: $2^i (1 + (-1)^i$). He will need direct proof of the problem instead.

Comment: I have answered the question asked in the title. The equality is true for non-negative integer $m,n$ such that either $m<n$ or $m$ and $n$ are of different parity.  In the body of OP only motivation for the question is given.

Comment: In that sense, I agree with you.

Comment: @Pseudocoder I have edited my answer to clarify this issue.